# HTMl text area

Tags: html, textarea

If we type something in the text area and press submit button, the values should be displayed on the same page under that. How to do that?

And make stay permanently on the page

Comment: http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=451

Comment: Stop re-asking this question over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need javascript.

```
<form onsubmit="document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = document.getElementById('tarea1').value;return false">
<textarea id="tarea1"></textarea>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help how to make it stay permanently on the page

Comment: you could either use a cookie to store the information or you could use a server side script language (e.g. perl php java asp).
if you want something like a shoutbox where everyone can add a short note you should use a server side script language.

an complete example for that can be found here:
http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=451

Answer (score 1):

You need some server side code, asp.net or PHP

Test for Post/Get parameters
Echo text in response

If you need to learn about forms and server side basics w3schools.com is the best place to start

Answer (score 1):

In order to store something permanently, you need to have a server running your webpage. You can't just create an HTML file that can get changed on the fly and have those changes become permanent. You'll need to learn a server language (PHP for example) and have a server (like Apache) that can display your page.

Is this what you're intending? to make an actual site, not just a webpage?

Comment: i have apache server with html how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Add a piece of JavaScript and attach it to `onClick` of the submit button. In the JavaScript, copy the value of the text area into the new place (assign the text to `innerHTML`) and also call `submit()` on the form.